# Moving 'typewriter' text box up screen using PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint

I'm trying to move a text box smoothly up a screen.

The box has an entry animation with the text set to appear by letter (to create a typewriter effect). I then want to click on a command button to make the box move smoothly up the screen.

The text box is called 'TxtPrint'.

When I click the button the text box disappears. I tried the code with other types of shapes and it works as intended, so there is a problem with how I am applying it to text boxes.

```vb
Private Sub Button_Click()

Dim objSequence As Sequence
Dim objTxt1 As Shape
Dim objEffect1 As Effect
Dim sld As Slide

Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
Set objTxt1 = sld.Shapes("TxtPrint")
Set objSequence = sld.TimeLine.MainSequence
Set objEffect1 = objSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=objTxt1, effectID:=msoAnimEffectFloat, trigger:=msoAnimTriggerOnClick)

objEffect1.EffectType = msoAnimEffectPathUp

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to use VBA for this. Just add the animation to the TxtPrint shape, then trigger it with a click on a shape. https://www.brightcarbon.com/blog/powerpoint-triggers-make-something-happen/

Comment: Thanks John. Yes I know how to do this in 'core' powerpoint, but I want to learn the basics of VBA so I can apply it to more complex problems where VBA is the only option. When I've learned VBA for Access and Excel I was able to get to a reasonable level from books and online courses, but there seems to be much less of that material available for Powerpoint VBA : this is why I've asked what is probably a really basic question. Thank you.

Comment: Your code successfully adds an animation to the TextPrint shape. You haven't defined the circumstances in which you're using this code: In edit mode? During a slide show? Is the code being run from a userform? Or a button shape on the slide? Or an ActiveX button? We can't reproduce your situation without the details.

Comment: Thanks John. I'm running it from a slide show.  The teleprinter effect is set in the animation pane to occur when the slide loads. The above code is linked to a command button on the slide : when clicked I want the text box to glide upwards to the top of the screen. Instead it disappears. When I use a shape instead of a text box, the code works as intended. However when I have a text box, when I click the button, the box just disappears rather than floating up.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the TextPrint box disappearing. I've recreated a presentation from your description and added your code. When I get to slide 3, I click on the shape to run the macro. Then I click on the slide and TxtPrint floats to the top as expected. Perhaps you could upload the file to a cloud service, then post a share link here to avoid wasting more time.